# how to add icon to android contact that link to my application

Tags: android

i want to add an icon to a specific contact upon it's _ID and link this icon action to my application.
i need this icon appear when user open contacts and select this user to view, here i want to put myicon under "Call cell", like whatsapp icon for the registered contacts

Answer (score 2):

please look into the below link for a detailed explanation with example [writing Sync provider](http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-1/)